# weird graphs with weird behaviours

Tags: trigonometry

i was playing around in desmos, trying to make the weirdest graph i could make, and i came up with this:

[image]
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7mtl3vtxfq?lang=pt-BR, different colors are different equations (it is not necessary to enter the link)

something i noticed is that they seem to always intersect and the angles seem to be most of the time a multiple of 90, but i dont event know where to start, because the equations are very hard to solve for y

the equations are:

$tan(x)^y=tan(y)^x$       (red)

$sin(x)^y=sin(y)^x$       (blue)

$tan(x)^y=sin(y)^x$       (purple)

$sin(x)^y=tan(y)^x$       (black)

any way of getting a vage idea of why any one of these is true?????????

Comment: Please type out the equations which you plotted on desmos rather than making us go back and forth from this site to that.

Comment: It is not true that the angles are always an integer multiple of $\pi/2$ (cf. the intersection of the black line with the purple line, bottom right graph)

Comment: Seconding @Ritam_Dasgupta,  it is a community standard here that all questions should be self-contained, IE require no clicking on external links.  This is both for convenience and to preserve the question for the future, when that link may no longer be valid.

Comment: ok i am going to put the equations here